# Numerically solving a matrix equation with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I want to find the $X$ that solves the matrix equation

$$ AX = B $$

with $A$ and $B$ known - $ A$ and $X$ are rectangular, $A$ is $n \times m $ and $X$ is an $m \times n$, with $m > n$.

(Specifically for my case, $ m = 250$ and $n = 15$.)

Also - $B$ is diagonal with non-zero entries (and is therefore invertible).

EDIT: for context, it's a bit of a distribution problem - $A_{ji}$ represents the maximum number of spaces that an entity $j$ can take up, in within a group $i$ - $X_{ij}$ is the ratio of entity $j$ in group $i$ and the diagonal entries of $B$ therefore present the total actual spaces taken up by entity $j$, across all groups $i$.

The groups here - and when I say groups I really mean "areas", indexed by $I$, are in this case chosen based of the different intersections of entities in an area, as all entities have an influence on one another. So this means $A$ is very sparse (usually, no more two or three entities are competing in a group) and also, it means that the ratio $X_{ij}$ can be assumed to be zero when $A_{ji}$ is zero.

I'm reading about interactive methods [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method#Convergence_of_Krylov_subspace_methods) but I'm not sure how to deal with the following additional complications:

- I know that the rows of $X$ must add up to be less than or equal to 1.
- Moreover, I know that the entries of $X$ lie between 0 and 1.
- A and X are both rectangular
- I expect that the system has many solutions, so that $ \det(A^TA) = 0 $ (not sure I can use CG for this reason)

If it helps at all, $A$ is pretty sparse (and $B$ is diagonal!) and furthermore we can deduce things about $X$ based on the sparseness of $A$. Concretely, if $A_{ij} = 0 $ then we know that $X_{ji} = 0$.

How would I solve this - and how would I incorporate this kind of extra information into these algorithms?

Comment: is $A$ tall or wide? Is $B$ invertible?

Comment: thanks - added that info!